# Add first row decimal value to next rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table, as below and its contains customer electricity volume for the period as. Available data like

```
OwnerID StartDate   EndDate     Volume
---------------------------------------
 1      2019-01-01  2019-01-15  10.40
 1      2019-01-16  2019-01-31   5.80
 1      2019-02-01  2019-02-10   7.90
 1      2019-02-11  2019-02-28   8.50
```

For this `OwnerID = 1`, having existing some volume 0.90. This should apply first row (add)

1. Get the whole number and decimal part value
2. the first row returned decimal value should add to next row and vice vera.

ExistingVolume  - 0.90

So expected result set should like:

```
OwnerId StartDate   EndDate     CalulatedVolume  AppliedExistingVolume(0.90)   RemainExistingVolume 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   2019-01-01  2019-01-15         11                0.60                   0.30
    1   2019-01-16  2019-01-31          6                0.20                   0.10
    1   2019-02-01  2019-02-10          8                0.10                   0.00
    1   2019-02-11  2019-02-28          8                0.00                   0.50
```

Could you someone suggest how to achieve this is in SQL query?

Comment: Why does 10.4 go to 11 but 8.5 go to 8?  This is also very similar to your other question, but you have not accepted that answer.

Comment: add ExistingVolume 0.90  to the first value 10.4

Comment: It seem nice question.It will be great if you just explain the output of each row and increase the excitement.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The example below uses a cumulative sum and a few CTE's to calculate those 2 columns.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> create table yourtable
> (
>   Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   OwnerID int not null, 
>   StartDate date not null, 
>   EndDate date not null, 
>   Volume decimal(16,2) not null
> );
>
> insert into yourtable
>  (OwnerID, StartDate, EndDate, Volume) values       
>   (1, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-15', 10.40)
> , (1, '2019-01-16', '2019-01-31', 5.80)
> , (1, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', 7.90)
> , (1, '2019-02-11', '2019-02-28', 8.50)
> ;
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> ;with CTE_EXISTING_VOLUMES AS
> (
>    select *
>    from (values
>      (1, 0.9)
>    ) q(OwnerId, ExistingVolume)
> )
> , CTE_DATA AS
> (
>   select t.*, c.ExistingVolume
>   , ceiling(t.Volume) - t.Volume as VolumeRemainder
>   , sum(ceiling(t.Volume) - t.Volume) 
>       over (partition by t.OwnerID
>             order by t.StartDate) as CumSumVolumeRemainder
>   from yourtable t
>   left join CTE_EXISTING_VOLUMES c
>     on t.OwnerID = c.OwnerID
> )
> , CTE_DATA2 AS
> (
>   select *
>   , ceiling(Volume) as CalculatedVolume
>   , IIF(ExistingVolume < CumSumVolumeRemainder, 0.0, (ceiling(Volume) - Volume)) as AppliedExistingVolume
>   from CTE_DATA
> )
> select OwnerId, StartDate, EndDate
> , CalculatedVolume
> , AppliedExistingVolume
> , case
>   when AppliedExistingVolume > 0
>   then ExistingVolume - CumSumVolumeRemainder
>   else VolumeRemainder
>   end as RemainExistingVolume
> from CTE_DATA2;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> OwnerId | StartDate           | EndDate             | CalculatedVolume | AppliedExistingVolume | RemainExistingVolume
> ------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :--------------- | :-------------------- | :-------------------
>       1 | 01/01/2019 00:00:00 | 15/01/2019 00:00:00 | 11               | 0.60                  | 0.30                
>       1 | 16/01/2019 00:00:00 | 31/01/2019 00:00:00 | 6                | 0.20                  | 0.10                
>       1 | 01/02/2019 00:00:00 | 10/02/2019 00:00:00 | 8                | 0.10                  | 0.00                
>       1 | 11/02/2019 00:00:00 | 28/02/2019 00:00:00 | 9                | 0.00                  | 0.50
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f28288ccdeef258491f1a38dbc86774)*

Answer (score 0):

When requirement is absolutely clear then you can think of better solution i.e. `Set Based Approach`

When requirement is not so clear then you think of solution like `RBAR`.

Suppose I was to calculate the output in Excel then what formula I will apply ?

There have to have some formula but requirement is not clear.

```
create table #temp(OwnerID int, StartDate date,EndDate date,Volume decimal(5,2))
insert into #temp values
  (1,'2019-01-01','2019-01-15', 10.40)
 ,(1,'2019-01-16','2019-01-31', 5.80)
 ,(1,'2019-02-01','2019-02-10', 7.90)
 ,(1,'2019-02-11','2019-02-28', 8.50) 

 declare @ExistingVolume decimal(5,2)=0.90

 ;with CTE as
 (
  select *
 ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ownerid order by startdate)rn 
  from #temp 
  ),
  CTE1 as
  (
  select ownerid
  ,startdate,enddate,Volume
  ,Cast((c.Volume+@ExistingVolume) as int)  CalulatedVolume
  ,Cast((c.Volume+@ExistingVolume) as int)-c.Volume as AppliedExistingVolume
  ,cast((c.Volume+@ExistingVolume-
  cast((c.Volume+@ExistingVolume) as int) )as decimal(5,2)) as RemainExistingVolume
 ,rn
  from CTE C where rn=1 

  union all

  select c.ownerid
  ,c.startdate,c.enddate,c.Volume
  ,cast((c.Volume+c1.RemainExistingVolume) as int) as CalulatedVolume
   ,cast((c.Volume+c1.RemainExistingVolume) as int)-c.Volume as AppliedExistingVolume
  ,cast(((c.Volume+c1.RemainExistingVolume)
  -cast((c.Volume+c1.RemainExistingVolume) as int)) as decimal(5,2))
  ,c.rn
  from CTE C 
  inner join CTE1 C1 on c.OwnerID=c1.OwnerID
  where c.rn=c1.rn+1 
  )



  select ownerid, 
  startdate,enddate
  ,CalulatedVolume
  ,case when AppliedExistingVolume<0 then 0 
  else AppliedExistingVolume end as AppliedExistingVolume
  ,RemainExistingVolume
  from CTE1


 drop table #temp
```